# how to use -filter and vf command on ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this code for crop video:

```
crop=2/3*in_w:2/3*in_h
```

And using change colors:

```
-vf mp=eq2=3.0:0.0:1.0:0.0:3.0:3.0:1.0
```

How do i using combine this command?
I tried this code but colors are not working

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf mp=eq2=3.0:0.0:1.0:0.0:3.0:3.0:1.0 -filter:v "crop=2/3*in_w:2/3*in_h" out.mp4
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Merge your 2 filters like below:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "mp=eq2=3.0:0.0:1.0:0.0:3.0:3.0:1.0, crop=2/3*in_w:2/3*in_h" out.mp4
```